# What's "EXISTS WIN://SYSAPPID" condition in "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" ACL?

Tags: windows, acl, ntfs

I noticed that access rights in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` for *Users* have a special "condition" applied: `EXISTS WIN://SYSAPPID`.

[image: ACL condition EXISTS WIN://SYSAPPID]

I didn't find anything about ACL conditions or how I could create and utilize such kind of thing.

How can I create and utilize ACL conditions?

Comment: Support for Authz conditional ACEs was added to kernel access checks in Windows 8. They're not well supported with existing command-line tools. They're most easily handled with SDDL string security descriptors. e.g., `(XA;;0x1200a9;;;BU;(Exists WIN://SYSAPPID))` conditionally grants (XA) read and execute access (0x1200a9) to users (BU) when the effective access token has an attribute named "WIN://SYSAPPID". Another example, `(XA;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU;(WIN://SYSAPPID Contains "MICROSOFT.WINDOWSSTORE_8WEKYB3D8BBWE"))` uses the "Contains" operator to check for a specific value of the attribute.

Comment: In Windows 8+, support for Authz conditional ACEs was added to kernel access checks because (at least in part) they're used extensively in "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" to conditionally grant access to standard users only for a given user's installed apps. This was integrated into `CreateProcessW`, which gets the information to create the custom access token from fields in the app execution alias, which, if enabled for an installed app, is in the user's "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps" directory.

Comment: The specification for a conditional ACE is detailed in [\[MS-DTYP\] 2.4.4.17 Conditional ACEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/10dc22eb-788d-4343-b556-0b6969fe58ca). Also see [\[MS-DTYP\] 2.5.3.1.5 EvaluateAceCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/bb4ad6b3-6a11-4b2d-b5b0-b17456147c46) and [\[MS-DTYP\] 2.5.1 Security Descriptor Description Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/4f4251cc-23b6-44b6-93ba-69688422cb06).

Comment: Marvellous information. Want to provide an answer, so I can vote for it and close this question?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and it wouldn't let me edit that entry to grant access to `%USERS%`
I followed [this](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-access-control-entry-is-corrupt-error-on-windows/) tutorial. It has 3 workarounds for this problem.

For me, `Method 2: Changing the owner to Users` worked:

> Perhaps the most effective fix for this particular issue is to change
> the Owner of the folder/file and to take full ownership of it. After
> doing this, you should be able to edit the permissions without
> encountering the ‘Access Control Entry is Corrupt‘ error.
>
> 1. Right-click on the folder or file that you’re having issues with and
>    choose Properties from the context menu.
> 2. Once you’re inside the Properties screen, select the Security tab, click on the
>    Advanced button associated with Permissions.
> 3. Inside the Advanced Security Settings, click on the Change button associated with the
>    Owner.
> 4. Inside the Select User or Group, type Users inside the text box, then click
>    on Check Names to verify. If the syntax is replaced correctly, click
>    Ok to save the changes. Then click Apply at the previous window to
>    make the change permanent.
> 5. Try to modify the permissions accordingly
>    and see if you still see the error message.

Comment: Not the same problem. This workaround has nothing to do with `WIN://SYSAPPID`. The tutorial linked here teaches how to fix 'Access control entry is corrupt' error. But in this case it's not actually a corrupt entry, but a special permission/condition (Exists:WIN://SYSAPPID) for Users(Pc-Name\Users) and can't be removed.

Comment: On top of what @Coconut mentioned, I'd be concerned about the knock-on effects of changing permissions & ownership of a core Windows directory like this; I'd be especially concerned about security holes this may open. The linked tutorial doesn't mention these possibilities at all.